# How to reset network proxy settings

Tags: settings

Actually I'm having a problem in switching on the proxy switch whenever I try to switch on my proxy switch then it automatically gets switched.
so I think setting the network proxy setting may resolve this issue.

Comment: Which OS are we talking about?

Comment: What StackExchange community are we writing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy` in terminal the command will reset proxy settings.